# Apache2 config problem

Tags: apache-2.2

For using my Debian VPS for multiple domains , I did such actions:

removed the default one from sites-enabled/ and sites-available/ (config and the symbolic link) and I added this under sites-available/www.mysite.com :

```
<VirtualHost MYIP:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
Alias /media/ /home/myuser/mysite/media/
Alias /admin_media/ /home/myuser/django/Django-1.2/django/contrib/admin/media/
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myuser/mysite/wsgi.py
ErrorLog  /home/myuser/mysite/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/myuser/mysite/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have changed my ports.conf to:

```
NameVirtualHost MYIP:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # SSL name based virtual hosts are not yet supported, therefore no
    # NameVirtualHost statement here
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Lastly I enabled the new domain via the command:

```
a2ensite www.mysite.com
```

After restart I get this error:

```
myuser:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting web server: apache2apache2: Syntax error on line 281 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.birertek.com: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.birertek.com:1: <VirtualHost> was not closed.
 failed!
```

Please help this poor soul.

Answer (score 2):

The file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.birertek.com contains the configuration for the virtual host www.birertek.com.

The file should begin with

```
<VirtualHost>
```

which should be followed by various configuration options. There should be a closing

```
</VirtualHost>
```

at the bottom.

Check that there is a suitably placed `</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
[...] <VirtualHost> was not closed.
```

seems to be about your config being improperly formatted. Are you sure you didn't miss some slash/spelling mistake in the actual config? The provided snippet looks OK though, so I'm not sure why you would have something like this. By the way, what `DocumentRoot` are you using for your virtual hosts?